# PDF as appendix, but use full page

Tags: pdf, pdfpages, appendix

So, as you can see in the image, I have these mechanical drawings that I need to add to a document as the appendix. I'm using **pdfpages** to do so, but the result that I'm getting is that. I need the page to be the drawing, not that the drawing is like an image on the paper. In the image that an ANSI A format, but I have different formats (A0, A1, A3) and those dont look good either.

Maybe pdfpages is not the way to do it, but I can't find another way to do it. Can anyone help me?

[image]

Comment: Normally, `pdfpages` does what you want automatically. `\includepdf{example-image.pdf}` will scale the PDF to fill the whole page while maintaining aspect ratio. Can you show a short minimal working example?

Comment: The line I have that causes the problem shown in the picture is this one: \includepdf[pages=-]{Anexos/Paralelas.PDF}.

Answer (score 2):

`\includepdf` is a wrapper for `\includegraphics` and accepts all options of `\includegraphics`. Thus you can use options `trim` and `clip`. Eg:

`\includepdf[trim=50mm 20mm0 50mm 20mm, clip]{dummy.pdf}`

To see exactly what you are trimming, use these options first:

`\includepdf[frame, trim=50mm 20mm 50mm 20mm]{dummy.pdf}`